# Fermat' Last Theorem

Tags: solution-verification

Fermat‘s Last Theorem

Fermat‘s last theorem       (proofed by Andrew Wiles in 1994)

a^(i) – b^(i) <> c^(i) 
a, b, c, i are elements of N with a > b, i >1, i<>2; a, b, c are coprime.

I) We start the proof with exponent i=3

If a³ – b³ = c³ then:

c³ = p1³ * p2³ * …

We name the primefactors p1 * p2 * p3 …  prime factorbases P(c) of c:

P(c) = p1 * p2 * p3 …

We get:

a³ – b³ = P(c)³

For a³ = P(c)³ + b³ we get the condition

a³ mod (c+b) = 0    (c+b) is a divisor of a³

a³ mod (P(c) + b) <> 0  (P(c) + b) is no divisor of a³

because a, b and P(c) are coprime , therefor  (P(c) + b) is coprime  a³

As a result we get:

a³ – b³ <> P(c)³

and

a³ – b³ <> c³

If the proof is correct, it would also be correct for  i>3.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It's not correct.  If $x$ and $y$ are coprime to $z$, it does not follow that $x+y$ is coprime to $z$.  Take $x=1$, $y=3$ and $z=4$.

Comment: Ok, it's not correct. Thanks.

Comment: It's not correct with 1. Other examples? Because a³ - 1³ <> c³